# WebBrowser control and HTTPS in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I am developing my first Windows Phone 8 Application. I have requirement to load facebook login page in WebBrowser control. I am facing an interesting issue now, When I test the app in my device. Links with https is not loading, it loads a page saying "We're having trouble with this sites security certificate" etc.

Does anybody face similar issue ? Do I need to make any settings in my application in-order to access https sites ?

Thanks in advance,
- Anwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer from Ben and it useful for u to solve the problem

[trusted companies issue secure IDs to websites](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130517193018AAvI3pW)

There's a couple possiblities here:

1) If you get the same error acessing the site on other devices (make sure the URL says https, not http), it means it's the sites problem. Your phone is warning you that it doesn't trust them- for all you know, you're not actually connecting to the site at all.

2) If you don't get the same error on other devices, it means that your phone somehow lost its list of trusted ID issuers. There is a way to add certificates back, but it's probably easier at this point just to wipe the phone and restore it to factory settings.

Comment: That works !. I rest the phone, now I can access https sites in webcontrol. Thank you likewer